# Plot precedence while plotting adx and price oscillator in [pine- script]

Tags: plot, pine-script

Hi I am a newbie to pine editor, I am trying to plot Price oscillator and ADX in the same window with the same precedence, but whenever I plot them ADX is coming on the top but it should be in reverse order. Plots are not coming correctly (when plotted individually it shows correctly). Please find the code which I have used and let me know where it needs to be corrected?

```
//@version=4
    study(title="Price Oscillator", shorttitle="PPO", format=format.price, precision=2)
    shortlen=input(12, minval=1)
    longlen=input(26, minval=1)
    src = input(close, title="Source")
    short = ema(src, shortlen)
    long = ema(src, longlen)
    po = (short - long)/long*100
    adxlen = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing")
    dilen = input(14, title="DI Length")
    dirmov(len) =>
    up = change(high)
    down = -change(low)
    plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
    minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
    truerange = rma(tr, len)
    plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / truerange)
    minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / truerange)
    [plus, minus]
    adx(dilen, adxlen) =>
    [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)
    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)
    sig = adx(dilen, adxlen)
    plot(po, color=#990000, title="PPO")
    plot(sig, color=color.red, title="ADX")`
```

I have attached the snapshot of the window as well for your reference[plotting PPO and ADX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8CJc.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because they don't have the same scale. It would be much easier and reliable to simply use each one separately and overlay them on in the same pane, on different scales.

[image]

Comment: Hello Thanks, LucF, I was able to overlay them on the main pane (candlestick pane). how can I overlay these two on the different pane (New pane should overlay ADX and PPO only with candlesticks as a separate one).

Comment: You can move indicators where you need them using the indicator's dropdown menu, and "Move To" (see screenshot added to answer).

Comment: Thank you LucF, can I create an signal when they overlap with each other.

Comment: Yes. The best way to do that would be to calculate both signals in the same script, so you could define a compound condition on both their states. Note that this would not necessarily affect your current display setup. Even if one of your two indicators calculated both signals, it could still only plot one of them so you wouldn't be changing anything visually—just the calcs going on inside the script.

Comment: Thank you i was able to plot the signals as i wanted